# how to sort MySQL data according to values calculated outside the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

i have 2 MySQL tables: polls and candidates.candidates table stores name of candidates and position they vying for i.e candidates(candidate_name,Position)  The polls table stores every poll made by user while voting. The polls table structure is polls(candidate_name,Position). Assuming there is only one position of chairman and the candidates are 3 ; x,y and z. when a user votes for x, a row in table polls is filled with value (x,chairman). assuming there are 6 ballots cast and the table will look like this.

```
|y | Chairman|
|x | Chairman|
|z | Chairman|
|x | Chairman|
|y | Chairman|
|x | Chairman|
```

From this table, i want to display every candidate in it and the number of votes gained in a html table. the code to do this is

```
$cnameres=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT candidate_name FROM candidates WHERE Position ='Chairperson'");

            while($cname = mysqli_fetch_array($cnameres))
            {

                $v = $cname['candidate_name'];

                //total votes for each candidate

                $cand_ballot_count = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(Position) FROM polls WHERE Position ='Chairperson' and candidate = '$v'"));
                $y = $cand_ballot_count[0] ;        

            //echo candidate and votes

              echo "<tr align='left'>"; 
                echo"<td>" .$v ."</td>";
                echo"<td>". $y. "</td>";

            }
```

The result will be a html table called result table that looks like this.

```
| y | 2 |
| x | 3 |
| z | 1 |
```

**My question;**
how can i sort this data so that it could echo on the result table while sorted in a descending order like this.

```
| x | 3 |
| y | 2 |
| z | 1 |
```

remember the value to be sorted is not in the database. its just a result of counting rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `JOIN` the 2 queries into one like below

```
SELECT c.candidate_name, count(*) AS votes
FROM candidates c 
JOIN polls p ON c.candidate_name = p.candidate_name
WHERE c.Position = 'Chairperson'
GROUP BY c.candidate_name
ORDER BY votes DESC;
```

Here is the updated code snipped

```
$sql = "
SELECT c.candidate_name, count(*) AS votes
FROM candidates c 
JOIN polls p ON c.candidate_name = p.candidate_name
WHERE c.Position = 'Chairperson'
GROUP BY c.candidate_name
ORDER BY votes DESC;
";

$cnameres = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while($cname = mysqli_fetch_array($cnameres))
{

    $v = $cname['candidate_name'];

    //total votes for each candidate
    $y = $cname['votes'];

    echo "<tr align='left'>"; 
    echo"<td>" .$v ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $y. "</td>";
    echo "<tr/>";
}
```

Comment: didnt work for me. or maybe i didnt use the code well. if you can do the complete code please i. remember the code is running in a while loop and am not sure if your suggestion is out  of the roof.

Comment: it worked great.  If you don,t mind, i would also want to include a field percentage value for every candidate to the total casts vote. i.e  | x | 3 | 80% |
| y | 2 | 50% |
| z | 1 |20% |   how do i do that with your code?

Comment: You will first have to get the total votes for 'Chairperson' from a separate query `SELECT count(*) FROM polls WHERE Position = 'Chairperson'`. Store the total in variable `$totalvotes`. Then you will run the `JOIN` query to get results sorted by votes. In `while`  loop, you can calculate the percentage as `($y/$totalvotes)*100`

Answer (score 1):

You *should* be counting the rows in the database.  Then the ordering is trivial:

```
SELECT c.candidate_name, COUNT(p.candidate_name) as num_votes
FROM candidate c LEFT JOIN
     polls p
     ON c.candidate_name = p.candidate_name
WHERE c.Position = 'Chairperson'
GROUP BY c.candidate_name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

I am not sure if the `join` is necessary.  You have `position_name` and `position` redundantly in both tables.